# Material-UI not working (using nwb)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, nwb

[image: At the beginning:]
After click:
[image: After click:]

I try to test Material-UI components.
My steps:

1. [I installed nwb globally](https://github.com/insin/nwb): `sudo npm install -g nwb`
2. I created a new React application: `nwb new react-app myapp`
3. I look inside: `cd myapp`
4. [I edited nwb.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441825/nwb-build-react-app-creates-root-path-rather-than-relative-path) (since Webpack creates absolute path with "/"):

   ```
   module.exports = {
     webpack: {
       publicPath: ''
     }
   }
   ```
5. I installed requested plugin: `npm i --save react-tap-event-plugin`
6. I added font Roboto in `index.html`:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">`

7. I added links to icons (because Material-UI didn't show icons by default):

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

8. I installed and started a server:  `npm start  --auto-install`

After starting [I see an error](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html)

> Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...)

[image]

Only first button reacts on a click but it's not animation! And other buttons don't react on any clicks.

9. In the package.json I inserted ammendments in version of a plugin:

   "dependencies": {
       "react": "^15.4.1",
       "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
       "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
     },

based on information from: 
[ERROR in ./~/react-tap-event-plugin/src/injectTapEventPlugin.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670018/error-in-react-tap-event-plugin-src-injecttapeventplugin-js)

> Due to update in React, react-tap-event-plugin breaks
>   Change react-tap-event-plugin to ^2.0.0 in your package.json if using react version ^15.4.0.

Sorry, I don't have anymore any ideas how to fix it!
It's not working in Safari and in Chrome as well.
Thank you for any help!
All examples from official site [Material-UI/Components](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar)

[image]

Comment: $ npm list --depth=0

├── react@15.4.1
├── react-dom@15.4.1
└── react-tap-event-plugin@2.0.1

Comment: Do you need to use it with nwb only or just start to work with Material-UI?

Comment: I wanted to use nwb but not sure it's working with Material-UI...